# how to show that S and T have the same all linear combinations?

Tags: linear-algebra

If $S=\{v_1,v_2,v_3,v_4\}$ and $T=\{v_1,v_2,v_4\}$. $T$ and $S$ are sets of vectors in $\mathbb{R}^3$.

Then why we should set $v_3= v_1,v_2,v_4$ to show that $S$ and $T$ have the same all linear combinations?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> If $S=\{v_1,v_2,v_3,v_4\}$ and $T=\{v_1,v_2,v_4\}$. $T$ and $S$ are sets of vectors in $\mathbb{R}^3$.

Note that $S=T\cup\{v_3\}$ so you definitely have $\mbox{span}\,T \subseteq \mbox{span}\,S$ with the equality $\mbox{span}\,T = \mbox{span}\,S$ if (and only if) $v_3 \in T$ but that means you should be able to write $v_3$ as a linear combination of the vectors in $T$. So:

> Then why we should set $v_3= v_1,v_2,v_4$ to show that $S$ and $T$ have the same all linear combinations?

This is a bit of a strange way to write it; you mean that you need to be able to find scalars $a,b,c$ such that $v_3= av_1+bv_2+cv_4$.

Comment: could you please explain what does expression mean ? v3∈T

Comment: That means "$v_3$ is an element of $T$"...

Answer (score 0):

Just show, that set $S$ contains linearly dependent vector. And you know that dimnesion of $R^{3}$ is 3. So it menas, that number of linearly independent vectors must be just 3, and by these vectors you can generate the whole space. The same space as you would get by lin. combinations of vectors from $T.$

Comment: The _maximum_ number of linearly independent vectors is 3 in a three-dimensional space; this doesn't mean $T$ is a linearly independent set.